# How Can I Read An HTML Document And Extract Image Names?

Tags: wpf

I'm developing an application in WPF, C# and VS2010 and am not sure how to proceed with this...

I am interested in an algorithm to obtain all the .jpg and .bmp images that are referenced within an html file.  How can I extract the body from within an html file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a pretty solid library for extracting elements from an HTML document. A simple view is to see it as a wrapper over XPATH with a nice API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx

The following pattern should work:

```
(http?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|gif))
```